# Apache Cassandra Data modeling

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datamodel

I need some help for a data model to save smart meter data, im pretty new working with cassandra.

### The data that has to be stored:

This is a example of 1 smart meter:

{"logical_name": "smgw_123",

"ldevs":

[{"logical_name": "sm_1", "objects": [{"capture_time": 390600, "unit": 30, "scaler": -3, "status": "000", "value": 152.361925}]},

{"logical_name": "sm_2", "objects": [{"capture_time": 390601, "unit": 33, "scaler": -3, "status": "000", "value": 0.3208547253907171}]},

{"logical_name": "sm_3", "objects": [{"capture_time": 390602, "unit": 36, "scaler": -3, "status": "000", "value": 162.636025}]}]

}

So this is **1 smart meter gateway** with the logical_name "smgw_123".

And in the **ldevs array** are **3 smartmeters** with their values described.

So the smart meter gateway has a relation to the 3 smart meters. And the smart meters again have their own data.

### Questions

I dont know how I can store these data which have relations in a no sql database (in my case cassandra).

Do I have to use than 2 columns? Like smartmetergateway (logical name, smart meter1, smart meter 2, smart meter 3)

and another with smart meter (logical name, capture time, unit, scaler, status, value)

???

Another problem is, all smart meter gateways can have different amount of smart meters.

I hope I could describe my problem understandable.

thx

Comment: If you want to use Cassandra, then I recommend to watch DS220 course on academy.datastax.com - they have meters example there.

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra data modelling, the first thing you should do is to determine your queries. You will model partition keys and clustering columns of your tables according to your queries.

In your example, I assume you will query your smart meter gateways based on their logical names. I mean, your queries will look like

```
select <some_columns> 
from smart_meter_gateway 
where smg_logical_name = <a_smg_logical_name>;
```

Also I assume each smart meter gateway logical names are unique and each smart meter name in ldevs array has a unique logical name.

If this is the case, you should create a table with a partition key column of smg_logical_name and clustering column of sm_logical_name. By doing this, you will create a table where each smart meter gateway partition will contain some number of rows of smart meters:

```
 create table smart_meter_gateway 
 (
     smg_logical_name text,
     sm_logical_name text,
     capture_time int,
     unit int,
     scaler int,
     status text,
     value decimal,
     primary key ((smg_logical_name), sm_logical_name)
);
```

And you can insert into this table by using following statements:

```
insert into smart_meter_gateway (smg_logical_name, sm_logical_name, capture_time, unit, scaler, status, value)
values ('smgw_123', 'sm_1', 390600, 30, -3, '000', 152.361925);

insert into smart_meter_gateway (smg_logical_name, sm_logical_name, capture_time, unit, scaler, status, value)
values ('smgw_123', 'sm_2', 390601, 33, -3, '000', 0.3208547253907171);

insert into smart_meter_gateway (smg_logical_name, sm_logical_name, capture_time, unit, scaler, status, value)
values ('smgw_123', 'sm_3', 390602, 36, -3, '000', 162.636025);
```

And when you query smart_meter_gateway table by smg_logical_name, you will get 3 rows in the result set:

```
select * from smart_meter_gateway where smg_logical_name = 'smgw_123';
```

The result of this query is:

```
smg_logical_name    sm_logical_name     capture_time    scaler  status  unit    value
smgw_123            sm_1                390600          -3      000     30      152.361925
smgw_123            sm_2                390601          -3      000     33      0.3208547253907171
smgw_123            sm_3                390602          -3      000     36      162.636025
```

You can also add sm_name as a filter to your query:

```
select * 
from smart_meter_gateway 
where smg_logical_name = 'smgw_123' and sm_logical_name = 'sm_1';
```

This time you will get only 1 row in the result set:

```
smg_logical_name    sm_logical_name     capture_time    scaler  status  unit    value
smgw_123            sm_1                390600          -3      000     30      152.361925
```

Note that there are other ways you can model your data. For example, you can use collection columns for ldevs array and this approach has some advantages and disadvantages. As I said in the beginning, it depends on your query needs.